# Why am I getting a IllegalStateException in ViewPager2 when hiding empty viewpager in my Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2

I have a really weird issue with my viewpager2 in my Android App.

Context :
On my home screen, I have a viewPager2.
At the beginning, it's empty. I call my api to know how many fragments the viewpager will contains (it's based on the localisation of the user).
With the result of my api, I create my fragments and attach my viewpager to the tablayout.

Some code to see what I'm doing :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ContentHomeFragment :
    LocationFragment<FragmentContentHomeBinding, ContentHomeViewModel>() {

    private lateinit var qaInformationAdapter: QaInformationAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        qaInformationAdapter = QaInformationAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        binding.viewPagerContent.adapter = qaInformationAdapter
        binding.tabDays.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                ... Some code to define day of the tab
                viewModel.setCurrentDay(day)
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                // No op
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                // No op
            }
        })

        binding.btnToGoOut.setOnClickListener {
            ... Navigate to other fragment
        }

        viewModel.apiInformation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { apiInfo ->
            displayExistingTab(apiInfo)
        }
    }

    private fun displayExistingTab(infoFromApi: List<InfoFromApi>) {
        tabTitle.clear()
        ... perform some code to define nbTab and content
        if (nbTab == 0) {
            binding.viewPagerContent.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.layoutUnknownInfo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            binding.viewPagerContent.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.layoutUnknownInfo.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        tabLayoutMediator?.detach()
        tabLayoutMediator =
            TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabDays, binding.viewPagerContent) { tab, position ->
                setTabInfo(tab, position, infoFromApi)
            }
        tabLayoutMediator?.attach()
        if (displayTodayTab) {
            displayTodayTab = false
            binding.tabDays.selectTab(binding.tabDays.getTabAt(todayTab))
        }

        qaInformationAdapter.nbItem = nbTab
    }

    private fun setTabInfo(
        tab: TabLayout.Tab,
        position: Int,
        infos: List<InfoFromApi>
    ) {
        val tabView = ItemTabHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        ... some code to define tab content (title, color ...)
    }

class QaInformationAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifeCycle: Lifecycle
) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifeCycle) {

    companion object {
        private const val NUM_ITEM_MAX = 4
    }

    var nbItem = NUM_ITEM_MAX
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun getItemCount() = nbItem

    override fun createFragment(position: Int) =
        QaInformationFragment.newInstance(Day.values()[position])
}
```

I think it's all what you need to understand what I'm doing here.

Issue :
Everything works fine except in one case :

- I have an issue with my api (which can append, it's not an issue), so my viewpager is empty. I'm hiding it and display the correct information for the user.
- If I go in another screen from this "empty" screen, I obtain a crash :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager2 does not support direct child views
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onViewAdded(ViewPager2.java:489)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchViewAdded(ViewGroup.java:5129)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5301)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5076)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5016)
        at androidx.transition.TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap(TransitionUtils.java:138)
        at androidx.transition.TransitionUtils.copyViewImage(TransitionUtils.java:64)
        at androidx.transition.Visibility.onDisappear(Visibility.java:404)
        at androidx.transition.Visibility.createAnimator(Visibility.java:257)
        at androidx.transition.Transition.createAnimators(Transition.java:744)
        at androidx.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1808)
        at androidx.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:300)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1093)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2126)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8653)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

This exception is going to drive me crazy !

It's not the first time I'm having an issue with viewpager2 which indicate no link with my code.

The only way to remove this issue is to remove this two line of code in `displayExistingTab` :

```
        if (nbTab == 0) {
            binding.viewPagerContent.visibility = View.GONE // THIS
            binding.layoutUnknownInfo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            binding.viewPagerContent.visibility = View.VISIBLE // AND THIS
            binding.layoutUnknownInfo.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```

I can do this, because it's not really important. The `layoutUnknownInfo` is above the `viewPagerContent`. But I want to understand why it's link to the issue ...

If anybody has an idea to understand this issue, I would be very grateful !

And sorry for the english mistakes !

Comment: It looks like you are using Transitions to move between your fragments? And your ViewPager2 is the root view of your fragment? If you change either of those things (e.g., either remove transitions you've set on each fragment or add a `FrameLayout` outside of your `ViewPager2`)
, does the error disappear?